# Have iTunes Link maker show localized images?

Tags: itunes

Using the [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/), is there a way to have the "Available on the App Store" image show up localized? The image (the one with the black background below) always show up in English and having it localized all way would be nice. I know Apple provides localized graphics for download, but it'd be nice to have work on the fly with the iTunes Link Maker.

[image]